# Normalize to scale

Tags: dynamical-systems

I have an 2-D array of data (**C**), where **C(:,1)** has values corresponding to **C(:,2)**. **C(:,2)** varies from **0.0001:0.0001:1**, i.e. 10,000 values. I need to calculate the **d(log(C(i,1))) / d(log(C(i,2)))**, which I do by simply calculating **log(C(i,1)) / log(C(i,2))**. But as **C(i,2)**, approaches **1**, the denominator approaches **zero**, and the quotient shoots up. One way to keep this in check would be to normalize it using a parameter, but I'm not sure how to do that. 
I actually want to plot this quotient, i.e. the slope **d(log(C(i,1))) / d(log(C(i,2)))** vs **log(C(:,2))**, and as C(i,2) approaches 1, the slope should converge to zero, to be able to study it.
Does anyone have an idea about this?